# Best way to structure Verilog module to allow for simulation clocks

Tags: fpga, verilog, verification

Quick question that I am likely missing an obvious solution for. I have a relatively simple Verilog design which I'll call *taco*, where the top-level design entity is **taco_top** (because I'm writing this before lunch).

It's the only module in the design with all relevant logic contained in **taco_top**. The design targets the ever-popular Lattice iCE40 UltraPlus FPGA. In **taco_top**, I'm using the iCE40's low-frequency and high-frequency oscillators to generate 10kHz and 6MHz clocks. There are no external clocks in the design; **taco_top**'s ports all correspond to physical I/O pins on the FPGA and the clocks I need are sourced from these internal oscillators.

In simulation, I want to replace these with simple dummy clocks with the appropriate period since I can't simulate the LFOSC and HFOSC primitives. So, I've created the appropriate simulation only clocks and kludged them into my design with `define which is not particularly elegant.

In writing a testbench, I would normally instantiate my **taco_top** module and feed it the appropriate stimuli, but those sim clocks are buried inside / not exposed at the top-level.

What's an elegant way to structure my design such that I can easily feed those clocks in simulation and maintain their behavior in the synthesized design?

Answer (score 1):

In our designs, we normally divide the design into two layers, like an onion. We call the outer layer the "pad ring" (e.g., `taco_io`), and it contains everything that's specific to the physical interfaces of the chip — I/O buffers, on-chip clocks, etc.

The inner layer is the "core" layer, and contains all of the actual application functionality. In other words, the functional hierarchy is implemented with `taco_core` as its top level. The functional simulation testbench instantiates `taco_core` only, where it has access to drive those clocks you're talking about.

Your `taco_top` is used for synthesis only. It just instantiates two modules: `taco_io` and `taco_core` and connects them together. It also connects `taco_io` to the actual external pins of the device.

Note that you could put all of those I/O bits right into `taco_top`, but we find that it's generally cleaner to put them in their own submodule (`taco_io`).